# how to repeat alarm in background

Tags: android

I am trying an alarm for every fifteen minute and problem is that I hear that alarm will work when app is not running, but in my case alarm works first time and even second time if app is on screen. else not.also  I want to know when first alarm is set and time was in previous time,alarm will start in recent time, but if I set pending intent for 24 hours and at that time mobile was shut down and I turned my mobile after one or two hours, will pending intent that was for a day work after 25 or 26 hours or not.please help 
here is my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
    Button btn;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bt);

        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,13);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,54);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,13);
                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,54);
                calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,1);
setAlarm(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
            }
        });
    }
    private void setAlarm(long time) {

        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        //getting the alarm manager
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        //creating a new intent specifying the broadcast receiver
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MyAlarm.class);

        //creating a pending intent using the intent
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i, 0);
        //setting the repeating alarm that will be fired every day
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, time, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, pi);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm is set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

and here is my service

```
public class MyAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver{
    MediaPlayer mp;
    @Override
    public void   onReceive(Context context,Intent intent){
mp=MediaPlayer.create(context,R.raw.song);
mp.start();
    }
}
```

manifest is here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.bilal.pkr">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"></uses-permission>


    <application

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COPLETED"></action>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver
            android:name=".MyAlarm"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: U have to reset your alarms after phone starts from shut down, 
User boot receivers to get event of phone restarts  Use this link 
https://www.dev2qa.com/how-to-start-android-service-automatically-at-boot-time/

Comment: Tarun thank you,but it is not working when app is going in background before shut down of mobile. can you tell me what is wrong here? perhaps i am missing something?

Answer (score 0):

```
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, pi);
```

Use this.

Comment: Please use proper [formatting for the code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Also, provide appropriate reasons as to why your answer would work

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.